# Agora Token Service - How do RTC tokens translate to USD?

Tags: payment, agora.io, pay-per-view

I am not a developer. I'm just starting. I like to work backwards. I'm trying to reverse engineer how online education works. As far as I know Agora API/SDK can very easily be built into a web app and RCT tokens allow for scheduling and monetization.

Where does the USD come into play? Does Agora help with that or is it Stripe etc?

Many thanks for reading my first question.

Answer (score 1):

Agora doesn't offer a payment service for you end-user. You'll need to build the monetization for your app. You can use analytics and usage metrics from the dashboard to calculate end-user billing.